# Disjoint union of manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

Is the disjoint union of an arbitrary number of $n$-manifolds, again a $n$-manifold?

I only found a result that proves this for countably many manifolds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That depends upon your definition of manifold, but by the usual definition they are second countable. And that excludes the possibility of being an infinite non-countable union of disjoint manifolds.

Comment: The disjoint union of paracompact spaces is always paracompact. But usually (?) manifolds are required to be second-countable (which implies paracompactness), and this excludes uncountable unions.

Comment: @PaulFrost You're right! I shall edit my answer. Thank you.

Comment: Yes what @PaulFrost says makes sense, or alternatively when taking the definition with paracompactness, the fact that $M$ must have countable many connected components is violated